# If $X$ and its dual $X^*$ have the Radon-Nikodym property then $X$ contains no copy of $c_0$.

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space; the associated dual space is denoted by $X^*$ such that $X$ and its dual $X^*$  have the  Radon-Nikodym property.

Why $X$ contains no copy of $c_0$?

An idea please.

Comment: Contains a copy ... in the sense of linearly homeomorphic?

Comment: in the sense: $X$ has a subspace isomorphic to one of $c_0$

Comment: $c_0$ does not have the RNP; but if $X$ has the RNP, then so does each of its closed subspaces.

Comment: See Diestel & Uhl *Vector Measures* for all basic facts about RNP...

Comment: Which chapter, mister @GEdgar?

Answer (score 0):

Reference

*Diestel, J.; Uhl, J. J. jun.*, Vector measures, Mathematical Surveys. No. 15. Providence, R.I.: American Mathematical Society (AMS). XIII, 322 p. $ 35.60 (1977). [ZBL0369.46039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0369.46039).

Chapter III, Section 3, Theorem 2.

> *A Banach space has the Radon-Nikodym property if each of its closed separable linear subspaces has this property.*
>   *If a Banach space has the Radon-Nikodym property, so does each of its closed linear subspaces.*

Let $X$ have the RNP.  (No assumption about $X^*$.)  Then any closed subspace $Y$ of $X$ also has RNP.  Therefore, $Y$ is not isomorphic (= linearly hmeomorphic) to $c_0$.